# Magento Frontend Login not working after Server migration

Tags: php, magento, authentication

After migrating a magento (1.9.0.1) project from an old server to a new one (only difference should be PHP 5.5. instead of 5.3) the frontend customer login suddenly doesn't work any more.

I get no errors, the log is empty as well, after sending the login form I am redirected back to the same form without any feedback and the user is still not logged in.

I tried to inspect what's happening in the core and it seems that in the customer validatePassword function the getPasswordHash() returns an empty string. But I looked it up in the database, there is definitely a value set. Did anyone experience this before and knows a solution?

The cookie_path is set to NULL, website_id is also correctly set to 0.

Comment: clear `cache` and check your magento logs

Comment: I cleared the cache and the logs do not contain any useful hints. system.log only has a notice and the last entry in exception.log is from september last year. any other suggestions?

Comment: @Chi Did you migrate from a lower version of Magento to Magento 1.9.01? Can you share frontend url of site?

Comment: is your session and cache directories are writable?

Comment: the Magento Version stayed the same, I only moved the files and database from one server to another

Comment: var/session and var/cache are 777

Comment: try to update `cookie_httponly` too with `value = 0` in your `core_config` table

Comment: I tried changing cookie_httponly to 0 (and deleted the cache after changing it) but the login still doesn't work.

Comment: had you clear your `log` tables?

Comment: which ones would that be? should I clear all tables that start with log_ ?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found the answer(s):

1: the Users I tried loggin in with were created in the backend and had the wrong website ID set. So a login wouldn't work

2: the login Form didn't have a formkey, which, for some odd reason, worked before. But after adding

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

it worked just fine.